# How is it that I can add properties to a closure in anonymous self executing function?

Tags: javascript

why is it that when I do this:

```
x = 5
(function bla(varX){
    varX = 7; console.log(x); //7
})(x);
console.log(x); //5
```

the `x` doesn't change, since it's in a closure if I understand correctly,
but here:

```
x = {a:5}

(function bla(varX){
    varX.a = 7; console.log(varX.a);
})(x)
console.log(x.a); //7
```

Why does `x.a` gets overwritten and `x` doesn't?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In both functions you have a global x (on line one) and a local x (`function bla(x){`).

In the first example, you are just changing the values of a series of variables. Changing the value of the local x doesn't touch the global x.

In your second example, you are passing a **reference to the object** you create to the function, not a copy of it. In the function you **modify that object** by assigning a new value to one of it's properties. The value of both the global and local x remains the same (a reference to the object).

Answer (score 3):

You can do the same thing with any other function:

```
var o = {};
function f(x) {
  x.val = "foo";
}
f(o);
console.log(o.val);
```

The object is floating around somewhere on the heap, and both `x` are merely references to that object. You only need a reference to it to alter an object, no matter how you got that reference.

On the other hand, the statement `x = ...;` simply overwrites the local variable to refer to something else. This is also why JS does *not* have "pass by reference" by the traditional (and more useful) definition.

Comment: thanx, can you elaborate a bit about this referencing thing..? :)